# Can I toggle inlay hints with a keystroke in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, inlay-hints

I'm using Rust, but this is probably language-independent.  Sometimes I find inlay hints for types, etc. very helpful, but sometimes they are in the way.  Is there a way to turn them on and off with a keystroke?

Comment: I find typing "Toggle Inlay Hints Globally" in the Search Everywhere window (shift,shift) more convenient than toggling it with a keystroke. Using it frequently that way is even more convenient because it is put in the recent actions; you only need to perform shift,shift,enter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Go to Preferences, then Keymap, and search for "inlay".  There you will find an entry called "Toggle Inlay Hints Globally" which probably is not bound to a key.  That's the one you want; bind it to whatever keystroke(s) you like.

[image: IntelliJ Preferences for Inlay Hints]